# Error when creating a page using publishing page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting error when creating a page using publishing page. I really appreciate your response.

Regards,
Moss

Comment: Without any details, its hard for anyone to help you

Comment: Please put into your question what exactly the error is, and the source code that is generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the SharePoint logs?

Use [ULS Viewer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2009/12/22/uls-viewer-for-sharepoint-2010-troubleshooting.aspx) and dive into the SP Logs.